# How to self reference a function?

Tags: function, go

Below code in python:

```
def print_all(x):
   print(x)
   return print_all
```

---

allows to call `print_all(1)(2)` or  `print_all(1)(2)(3)(4)`

---

**Edit**

Another example in python:

```
def print_sums(x):
   print(x)
   def next_sum(y):
      return print_sums(x+y)
   return next_sum

print_sums(1)(3)(5)
```

---

which maps to syntax:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type printsumfunctype func(x int) printsumfunctype

func printSums(x int) printsumfunctype {
    fmt.Println(x)
    var nextSum func(y int) printsumfunctype
    nextSum = func(y int) printsumfunctype {
        return printSums(x + y)
    }
    return nextSum
}

func main() {
    printSums(1)(2)(3)
}
```

In GoLang, function is first class

1) What is the syntax to self reference a function in GoLang?

2) What is the preferred naming convention to define types like `printsumfunctype`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You define a recursive function type:

```
type Printer func(interface{}) Printer

func printAll(x interface{}) Printer {
    fmt.Println(x)
    return printAll
}

func main() {
    printAll(1)("Hello")
}
```

For the new code, you would write

```
type Sink func(int) Sink // not really different, is it?

func printSums(x int) Sink {
    fmt.Println(x)
    return func(y int) Sink {
        return printSums(x + y)
    }
}
```

A useful naming convention is to just name the types after their functions. In both of these cases, `Printer` (basically function verb + "er") works. Or, the more generic term `Sink` also fits, as it's a black hole that you can just keep dumping items into. I don't think there's any rule for it; these types aren't very common. Just pick a descriptive name.